# « Sait-on jamais » et autres rhétoriques

Tags: grammaire, négation, questions, adverbes

Plusieurs choses me fascinent dans cette expression que je n'arrive pas à décortiquer.

> Cela me semble impossible, mais sait-on jamais…

1. Tout d'abord quel est son statut ? question, affirmation, exclamation ?
   Les trois ponctuations `?`, `.`, `!` sont-elles acceptables ? (sans parler de l'interrobang). Grammaticalement, l'inversion sujet–verbe semble indiquer que c'est une question, mais, pour formuler une exclamation (ou une affirmation), est-ce que :

   > Cela me semble impossible, mais « sait-on jamais » !

   serait la bonne façon d'exprimer ou de comprendre cette phrase ?
2. Aussi, il me semble qu'il s'agit là d'une tournure grammaticale positive (malgré le *jamais*) qui est différente de « *ne sait-on jamais* ». Exemple plus parlant¹ :

   > Mange-t-on jamais du pain avec la soupe ? (sous entendu… non, on n'en mange pas)
   >
   > Ne mange-t-on jamais du pain avec la soupe ? (sous entendu… si, on en mange)
3. Ces questions qui n'attendent aucune réponse semblent rentrer dans la catégorie des questions « rhétoriques » ; le *jamais* les rend-elles « explicitement » rhétoriques ? Je pense à des formulations qui utilisent le verbe *pouvoir* ou *devoir* et qui n'auraient pas ce caractère explicite :

   > Peut-on savoir ? Ne peut-on pas savoir ?
   >
   > Doit-on en manger ? Ne doit-on pas en manger ?

Comment fonctionne ce « sait-on jamais » ?
Je cherche en particulier des précisions, des références grammaticales sur cette utilisation de *jamais*, ou des erreurs d'appréciation dans tout ça.

—
<sup>1. Avec COD offert gratuitement.</sup>

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'après le [Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais) (*jamais* I.B.1), c'est une formulation elliptique d'une question rhétorique. Le mot *jamais*, dans cette tournure interrogative, indique que l'on demande si l'affirmation correspondante peut être vraie ne serait-ce qu'une fois : on pourrait dire verbeusement « Existe-t-il au moins un cas où l'on puisse savoir ? ». Sans le mot *jamais*, la question pourrait signifier « Sait-on maintenant, dans ce cas ? » ou « Est-il habituel que l'on sache ? ».

> *Il se consola de cette adhésion de second ordre lorsqu'il eut reçu des coups dans la bagarre de la rue Damrémont : il disait qu'il aurait pu mourir, sait-on jamais ?* (Paul Nizan, *La Conspiration*, 1938).

Ce n'est pas le mot *jamais* en lui-même qui fait que la question est rhétorique, mais plutôt le caractère figé de l'expression et la généralité complète de la question. Si l'on regarde les sens du mot *[jamais]([Trésor de la langue française](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais)* de plus haut, on voit qu'en général le mot signifie « au moins une fois » — employé négativement, le sens est logiquement « aucune fois ». Dans une question, le mot *jamais* a tendance à rendre la question rhétorique, puisqu'il signale que la question ne s'applique pas à une situation particulière, mais cela n'a rien d'obligatoire (voir les exemples du TLF, §I.B). La phrase « sait-on jamais » est en principe interrogative, mais son aspect rhétorique et sa forme figée font qu'on l'écrit quelquefois comme une locution figée, affirmative.

> *Ensuite, on n'oublie surtout pas de montrer ce qu'on a de plus beau ! Sait-on jamais... Peut-être que le toubib, là, le régulier de Julie... peut-être qu'il va baver dessus... Ou bien le voisin, sait-on jamais.* ([Nathalie Saugeon, *Maman est morte*, 1997](http://books.google.fr/books?id=theq0XemzBwC&pg=PA63&dq=%22sait-on+jamais%22&hl=en&ei=KqhzTsfQMuXd4QSmzvWWDQ&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=8&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBzge#v=onepage&q=%22sait-on%20jamais%22&f=false))

Au passage, les expressions « sait-on jamais ? » et « on ne sait jamais » sont presque synonymes, mais presque seulement. Le TLF les définit ainsi :

- *Sait-on jamais* : « S'emploie pour indiquer que ce qu'on exprime sous la forme d'une supposition peut se réaliser soudainement. » L'accent est mis sur le fait que la supposition, bien qu'improbable, est possible.
- *On ne sait jamais* : « Signale qu'il faut prendre en compte sérieusement une éventualité qui est formulée. » L'accent est mis sur le fait que la supposition a des conséquences importantes, il faut la prendre en compte parce que même si la probabilité est faible, le risque est élevé.

Comment: Tout ce que je voulais savoir ! Le sens originel serait donc proche de « pourquoi pas un jour » ou « pourquoi pas une fois », et c'est devenu une expression figée qui est utilisée pour dire que l'improbable pourrait se réaliser. Merci Gilles !

Answer (score 3):

Pour le point 2. c'est correct : [jamais](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais) peut être utilisé de manière positive, et donc sans corrélation avec une particule négative, signifie « à un moment quelconque ». L'exemple le plus courant est le « si jamais » qui signifie « au cas où » :

> Si jamais je visite Bruxelles, j'y mangerai des frites.

Answer (score 0):

Voici ma propre interprétation de "sait-on jamais..."

Qui dit "sait-on jamais..."?

Évidemment, c'est la personne qui énonce ces mots.

Mais en grammaire, "On" n'inclut pas toujours la personne qui parle.

Donc logiquement, on peut insinuer que c'est "les autres" qui ne savent pas.

Conclusion: la personne qui dit "sait-on jamais..." connait probablement la réponse... d'où les points de suspension... qui ouvre la piste à une éventualité.