# « [...] fond plus vite que jamais » : analyse ?

Tags: grammaire, verbes, négation, adverbes, ellipse

> La glace de l'Antarctique fond plus vite que jamais. (titre d'un article dans [*La Presse*](https://www.lapresse.ca/environnement/climat/201901/14/01-5210989-la-glace-de-lantarctique-fond-plus-vite-que-jamais.php))

J'ai lu plusieurs contributions ([1](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/23303), [2](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/31037), [3](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/1205)) ; je ne suis pas désaltéré.

---

Peut-on préciser exactement de quel emploi de l'adverbe *jamais* ([TLFi](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/jamais), [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3093)) il s'agit et indiquer ce qu'on aurait omis au juste et quelle est la nature de cette phrase ; peut-on dire qu'il s'agit simplement de l'ellipse de l'adverbe [*auparavant*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/auparavant) et dans ce cas y a-t-il une ellipse dans une ellipse, ou doit-on avoir recours à une particule de négation pour analyser et le cas échéant quelle en est sa valeur ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Il s'agit simplement du premier sens décrit dans le TLFi.

> **I.** − [Jamais n'est pas en corrélation avec une particule négative] À un moment quelconque, à quelque moment que ce soit.
>   ...
>   **D.** − [Dans une prop. compar.]
>   **1.** [La compar. est une prop. attributive] *Cette situation est plus claire que jamais elle ne fut* (Nizan, *Chiens garde*, 1932, p. 78).
>   Rem. Dans cette constr. ne n'a qu'une valeur explétive.
>   − *P. ell. Cela est moins vrai que jamais. Elle m'est plus chère que jamais (*Ac.1835-1935*). *M. Messimy estima qu'il était plus nécessaire que jamais de n'avoir aucun incident de frontière* (Joffre, Mém., t. 1, 1931, p. 230). *L'enseignement des écoles est plus que jamais dérisoire : on forme des compositeurs comme on forme des ingénieurs* (Schaeffer, *Rech. mus. concr.*, 1952, p. 136).

On peut considérer qu'il y a ellipse, la phrase complète pouvant être :

> La glace de l'Antarctique fond plus vite que jamais **elle n'a fondu**.

ou

> La glace de l'Antarctique fond plus vite que jamais **elle ne l'a fait**.

La tournure est similaire à l'anglais *more than ever*. Cette dernière est très souvent suivie de *before* :

> *More than ever before*.

mais il me semble que c'est sous l'influence de l'anglais que l'on rencontre parfois :

> *Plus que jamais **auparavant***.

Answer (score 1):

Dans le 2<sup>e</sup> lien que vous citez, on y retrouve cet emploi du mot « jamais ».

[BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?t1=1&id=3093)

> Dans son sens positif, *jamais* veut dire « un jour quelconque, une fois, un moment passé ou futur ». On l'emploie souvent dans ce sens pour introduire une condition, dans une comparaison ou dans une phrase interrogative.
>
> Exemples :
>
> - J’irai en camping durant mes vacances **si jamais** la température s'y prête.
> - Depuis que mon frère a son nouvel emploi, il est plus riche **que jamais**.
> - La musique brésilienne est la plus joyeuse **que** j’aie **jamais** entendue.
> - L’as-tu **jamais** surpris à manger en cachette?

---

> *La glace de l'Antarctique fond plus vite que jamais.*

On peut également ajouter « auparavant » à la fin de la phrase :

> *La glace de l'Antarctique fond plus vite que jamais auparavant.*

ou ajouter une négation :

> *La glace de l'Antarctique n'a jamais fondu aussi vite.*